# Issue with UWP Binding in release only

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-binding, uwp

I am having an issue with data binding in my UWP application. I have a class with a property.

```vb
Public Class Settings
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _EditorFont As String
    Private _IsDirty As Boolean = False

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Event Dirtied As EventHandler

    Public Property EditorFont As String
            Get
                Return _EditorFont
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If value <> _EditorFont Then
                    _EditorFont = value
                    RaisePropertyChanged(NameOf(EditorFont))
                    MakeDirty()
                End If
            End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub RaisePropertyChanged(ByVal Name As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name))
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnDirtied(ByVal e As EventArgs) Implements ISaveable.OnDirtied
            RaiseEvent Dirtied(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub MakeDirty()
            If IsDirty = False Then
                IsDirty = True
                OnDirtied(EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also have a RichEditBox control that binds the font family to the property on my class:

```xml
<RichEditBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" AcceptsReturn="True" Padding="5,10,5,5" x:Name="Editor"
             TextChanged="Editor_TextChanged" FontFamily="{x:Bind Settings.EditorFont, Mode=OneWay}"
             SelectionChanged="Editor_SelectionChanged"
             Loaded="Editor_Loaded" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
```

The problem is that my binding seems to work fine when running the application in debug mode, but fails to work when running in release mode. I don't know what to do in troubleshooting this and I'm kind of at a loss in terms of finding anyone else with this same issue. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: For troubleshooting please add some dummy converter to your binding and check what value is getting passed.

Comment: I am trying to create a simple example to test but could not reproduce it in my side. Could you provide  a minimal reproducible sample so that we can look into it?